# move_uploaded_file() error on windows with wamp

Tags: php, windows, permissions

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(C:\wamp\www/uploads/a.mp3): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\display\uploadfile.php on line 206

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php75FD.tmp' to 'C:\wamp\www/uploads/a.mp3' in C:\wamp\www\display\uploadfile.php on line 206
```

var_dump:

```
array (size=1)
  'file' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'a.mp3' (length=5)
      'type' => string 'audio/mp3' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php75FD.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 4030592
```

tmp and upload directories have permissions set to everyone > Full Permissions

PHP has upload filesize set correctly

I have no idea why the file wont upload...

Edit:
Code:
http://pastebin.com/kFG2v2PJ

Comment: How you defined your path to mp3 file? Is it on the same folder where the code is...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem: `C:\wamp\www/uploads/`.

Change your slashes to backslashes and make sure the directory `C:\wamp\www\uploads\` exists. You could use the [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) constant to make your code work on multiple systems.

Also, without seeing your code, you need to make sure you're putting the correct paramaters in [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Edit after code:

Change

```
$target_path = APP_PATH."/uploads/";
```

to

```
$target_path = APP_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Comment: Well it seems upload != uploads...

Comment: @user2269807 what you just said makes no sense.

Comment: I mistyped the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

is your /uploads directory exists? if yes then check `var_dump($_FILES)` check if `$_FILES['uploaded']['error']`. contains 0, which means "no error"

Comment: this should be a comment. plus, he's also posted the output of var_dump: `'error' => int 0`