# move_uploaded_file not working anymore only changing some HTML and spelling & upload_tmp_dir not applying

Tags: php, file-upload

About 3 months ago I added a file upload to my website. Everything worked fine until now, now **move_uploaded_file returns false** and doesn't move the file to the right folder (without showing a error).

But I changed NOTHING on my website!

(Exept some HTML and spelling)

**I already checked following:**

1. $_FILES contains the correct file
2. The file in the Temporary Path Exists after uploading
3. The target Filepath is correct
4. Thestweise I gave "Everyone" full rights on both Folders
5. I checked Upload Size, etc. in php.ini
6. I tried to change the upload_tmp_dir but it didn't applied
7. Every other change in php.ini applies...

**My implementation (without validation part)**

```
$upload_folder = 'uploads/';
$filename = pathinfo($_FILES['datei']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['datei']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// validation ...
$new_path = $upload_folder.$filename.'.'.$extension;
if(!$error)
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['datei']['tmp_name'], $new_path);
    $db->setIcon("./" . $new_path, $filename);
}
```

**$_FILES var_dump**

```
array(1) { 
    ["datei"]=> array(5) { 
        ["name"]=> string(47) "1fa9075fe0117b3ca9ed5ac0f327597da2b45610_hq.jpg" 
        ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
        ["tmp_name"]=> string(27) "C:\Windows\Temp\php6DFD.tmp" 
        ["error"]=> int(0) 
        ["size"]=> int(41356)
    }
}
```

**phpinfo()**

```
Loaded Configuration File: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php.ini
file_uploads: On
max_file_uploads: 20
upload_max_filesize: 2M
upload_tmp_dir: C:\Windows\temp
```

Comment: *"(Exept some HTML and spelling)"* - You should include that in the question; there *might* be a typo or something.

Comment: Have you got enough disk space to store the new file ?

Comment: What error is it showing?

Comment: The spelling misstakes which i corrected were not in php code just HTML and Echos

Comment: There is more than enough disk space

Comment: `var_dump` your $_FILES and show is the file+permissions in the tmp folder after upload.

Comment: @JayBlanchard There is no error, the method move_uploaded_file() only returns false

Comment: @Gonios check the tmp folder. If it's full, then that's the reason. I've seen that before.

Comment: @ccKep Like i listed above the $_Files is 100% correct, the file exists in the Temp Path after uploading and i testweise set all Perissions for everyone...

Comment: I know you wrote it, but you didn't show it. You'd be suprised at the amount of users that come to SO, claim one thing and after talking to them for over an hour results are very different.

Comment: Also: If the file isn't moved, did you consider your validation triggers an error and your `if (!$error)` skips the moving part...? There's just too many missing parts to answer this question with any reasonable degree of certainty.

Comment: the if(!error) is right i allredy tested a var_dump of the method move_uploaded_file, but i cant find the temporary file in C:/Windows/temp/ ...

Comment: If you can't find the file in the tmp dir it seems your 2nd test-point isn't valid? What does `phpinfo();` print regarding `configuration file, file_uploads, max_file_uploads, upload_max_filesize, upload_tmp_dir`?

Comment: It seems you're on windows, so try using backward slashes instead of forward slashes (or the php constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`). `C:\path_to_your_php_script\uploads/bla.jpg` won't be valid. (See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946263/move-uploaded-file-error-on-windows-with-wamp)). Check your `display_errors` and `error_reporting` settings.

Comment: @ccKep The ony error i get is "Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference XXX" from another file ...

Comment: echo out `$_FILES['datei']['tmp_name']` and `$new_path` right before `move_uploaded_file` call and report back.

Comment: using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR seperator solved my problem thx for helping